# Adding multiple layers to a search of a model in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, model, where-clause

So in my website i am implementing a search functionality in which the user can enter a value for 3 fields. i want it to perform in a way where if all fields have input for example it performs the search on the first, then performs the next search on the results returned from the first search and finally the last search added on top of that. i have code that looks like this:

```
public function search()
{
 $input = Input::all();
 $users = User::all();
 $jobs = Job::all();
 if($input->industry!=null){
   $users = $users::where('industry', '==', $input->industry);
   $jobs = $jobs::where('user_id', '==', $users->id);
 }
if($input->location!=null){
   $jobs = $jobs::where('location', '==', $input->location);
 }
if($input->salary!=null){
   $jobs = $jobs::where('salary', '>', $input->salary);
 }
 return View::make('jobs.jobsList')->with(compact('jobs'))->with(compact('users'));
}
```

but i am getting the error trying to get property of non-object. any hints on how i could go about adding this functionality would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $input = Input::all();
```

`$input` is an array. `Input::all()` returns an array of all the elements in a GET and POST array, but you're trying to access it as object properties.

You can use the `has()` method to test if the Input contains that index:

```
if(Input::has('industry')){
```

But also a simple

```
 if(Input::get('industry')){
```

would work just as well here.

Also, I believe you'll be getting an error also when you call the models, you should do:

```
   $users = $users->where('industry', '=', Input::get('industry'));
```

or

```
   $users = Users::where('industry', '=', Input::get('industry'));
```

Comment: is the way im incrementing the layers right? after i changed the ifs to contain the has statements i got a new error. Class name must be a valid object or a string. thankyou for the help regardless

Comment: Could you post the actual error message? With line number etc.

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…/­app/­controllers/­JobController.php53

Comment: job controller line 53 being this if statement and i assume the other if statements would give the same error

    if($input::has('industry')){
       $users = $users::where('industry', '==', $input->industry);
       $jobs = $jobs::where('user_id', '==', $users->id);
     }

Comment: Don't want to sound harsh, but did you actually read my anwer? I provided you some code, but you went on using yours again. Please re-check the code I wrote. Both the lines you posted here in the comment are completely different from what I suggested

Comment: ugh im sorry for skimming your answer like that. even with the updated content in the if statements (as per the second half of your answer) i still get that same error saying the class name must be a valid object or a string

Comment: nevermind my ramblings i still had not matched your answer :(. sorry for the trouble and thankyou for the help kind sir

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped ;)